# In Verilog, how do I use a variable in logic

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Say I have the following code:

```
genvar i,j;
generate
for(i = 0; i < MAX; i = i + 1) begin: gen_blah
  for(j = 0; j < MAX; j = j + 1) begin: gen_foo
    assign match[i] = entry[j] = i;
  end
end
endgenerate
```

Is this a synthesizable expression? It seems like it should be since this will just unroll out into a bunch of compare-to-constant assignments. If not, how would I write this to accomplish that?

Comment: Have you tried this code in an actual synthesis and implementation workflow? Looking at the RTL and technology schematics such as those provided by ISE, as well as at any synth tool output or warnings, may be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No. Imagine unrolling this and typing it out by hand. The fist two lines would cause a multiply driven net:

```
assign match[0] = (entry[0] == 0);
assign match[0] = (entry[1] == 0);
```

However, if you get rid of the generates and do this with loops inside an always block then it will work:

```
always_comb begin
  for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i = i + 1) begin: gen_blah
    for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j = j + 1) begin: gen_foo
      match[i] = (entry[j] == i);
    end
  end
end
```

Inside this block you get multiple assignments to the same value but the last one "wins". I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with your code, so this might not actually perform the function you are looking for. If you are trying to see if any of the entries equal `i` then you should change it to:

```
always_comb begin
  for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i = i + 1) begin: gen_blah
    match[i]=0;
    for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j = j + 1) begin: gen_foo
      match[i] = match[i] || (entry[j] == i);
    end
  end
end
```